# Virtual function with template struct as return type?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

Here is what my situation looks like:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo 
{
    Foo() {}
    Foo(T data) : _data(data) {}

    T _data;
};

struct Holder
{
    Holder() {}
    Holder(int a) : foo(a) {}

    virtual Foo<int> getFoo() { return foo; }
    virtual std::string type() { return "holder"; } // EDIT 2 EDIT 3: added virtual

    Foo<int> foo;
};

struct HolderInt : public Holder
{
    HolderInt() {}
    HolderInt(int a) : Holder(a) {}

    std::string type() { return "holderint"; } // EDIT 2
};

struct HolderString : public Holder
{
    HolderString() {}
    HolderString(std::string a) : Holder(0), foo(a) {}

    Foo<std::string> getFoo() { return foo; } // here is the dilema
    std::string type() { return "holderstring"; } // EDIT 2

    Foo<std::string> foo;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Holder*> holders;
    holders.push_back(new HolderString());

    return 0;
}
```

I am looking for a way to make this happen.  The way I'm hoping to get this to work is to maintain a single getter, but if I'm missing something that would be very useful for my situation that would be great to know.

EDIT: I understand that virtual functions cannot have different return types, but I am looking for another option.  Sorry for not saying so before.

EDIT 2: After further reviewing my code, I have realized that I missed something important.  I have a "to string" function so to speak, which I will edit in.  This can help me differentiate between each struct type, even if they have the same foo.  I don't know how I didn't see this before I've been looking it over for a while now, but I am able to solve this problem using that virtual function.

Comment: You are missing the fact that a function can only return a single type; and you have two different getters returning two different types, a `Foo<std::string>`, and a `Foo<int>`. Whatever getter you come up with, it always returns the same type.

Comment: This can never work. `Foo<int>` and `Foo<string>` are not covariant types, and you can't overload a method based on return type alone.

Comment: Your example is missing a crucial part: a *use case*. Please show what you would *do* with `holders[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, try something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
  T data;

  foo() {}
  foo(T d) : data(d) {}

  void set(T d) { data = d; } // Good practice to also have a setter
  T get() { return data; }
};

struct holder_int
  : public foo<int>
{
  holder_int(int i) : foo(i) {}
};

struct holder_str
  : public foo<std::string>
{
  holder_str(const std::string& str) : foo(str) {}
};
```

This uses a single generic (template) struct `foo` which also has a generic (template) get function. Each struct that inherits from that struct sets the type in foo (if that makes sense). Basically, a struct that holds an integer will inherit from `foo<int>` and a struct that holds a double will inherit from `foo<double>`.

Comment: This is a great solution, but it won't work out in my code.  This generalized code that I made for this question is missing all of my other stuff that I have going on, and my project is build around the "holder" struct (in my actual code it would be a class) being the base and having other types of holders that don't necessarily have to have different type values.  I plan on making multiple other HolderString types where they have Data<string> but have different functionality.

Comment: Can the holder class be generic and have a generic getter/setter, and then all of the other holders inherit off of that generic holder? What is the significance of the foo struct.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work. At compile time the compiler must have a type for each variable. Let's pretend you could do something like what you want

```
// illegal code
struct Holder {
    virtual ? get() = 0;
};

struct HolderInt : Holder {
    int get() override { return 0; }
};

struct HolderString : Holder{
    std::string get() override { return ""; }
};
```

Now let's say you have a function taking a `Holder*`

```
void func(Holder* holder) {
    auto t = holder->get(); // type of t must be known at compile-time

    constexpr auto sz = sizeof t; // must be known at compile-time
    using Type = decltype(t); // must be known at compile-time
}
```

The type of `t` **must** be known at **compile-time**, but your code makes that impossible to know until run time.